# how to enable "Publishing Approval Workflow" using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I tried to activate "Publishing Approval Workflow" feature using the below powershell script,

```
Enable-SPFeature –Identity Publishing Approval Workflow  –url http:
```

But its not working.

Comment: what error u are getting ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the below script,

```
Enable-SPFeature –identity a44d2aa3-affc-4d58-8db4-f4a3af053188 -URL http://[UR Site URL]
```

Have a look at the below link too,

[Features and their GUID’s in SP2010](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7695.sharepoint-2010-list-of-features-id-displayname-and-scopes.aspx)